# How to set Timing on Times Ten from a stored function?

Tags: timesten

I want to enable TIMING on oracle TimesTen. Its working if i execute `TIMING 1` from ttsql command prompt but when I tried the command `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TIMING 1'`  from a function, i got the error **ORA-06512** `Syntax error in SQL statement  before or at: "TIMING", character position: 1`. Any pointers on this?

Answer (score 0):

setting the Timing ON worked . `SET TIMING ON;`